# how to use limit in codeigniter controller

Tags: php, ajax, pagination, codeigniter-3

I am doing ajax scrolling pagination. Controller is like below

```
<?php
require APPPATH . '/controllers/user/Usercontroller.php';

class PaginationController extends Usercontroller{

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model("Usermodel","",true);    
    }

    private $perPage = 5;

    public function index(){
        $tutorId=$this->session->userdata('cp_userid');
        $categorycourses=$this->Usermodel->getcourses($tutorId);

        $count = $categorycourses->num_rows();

        $data['details']=$categorycourses;          
        $this->load->view("user/pagination_view",$data,true);
    }
}
?>
```

$count variable contains 5 data, I want to send 3 for first page and remaining for second page. How to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this...

**Model:**

```
function getcourses($tutorId, $limit = null) {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('courses');
    $this->db->where("tutorId", $tutorId);
    //$this->db->order_by("name", "asc");

    if($limit!=''){
       $this->db->limit($limit);
    }
    $query  = $this->db->get();

    $courses = array();
    foreach ($query->result() as $row)
        array_push($courses, $row);

    return $courses;     
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public function index(){
    $tutorId = $this->session->userdata('cp_userid');
    $limit = 3;
    $categorycourses = $this->Usermodel->getcourses($tutorId, $limit);
    //$categorycourses=$this->Usermodel->getcourses($tutorId);

    $count = $categorycourses->num_rows();

    $data['details'] = $categorycourses;      

    $this->load->view("user/pagination_view", $data, true);
}
```

Comment: My model code is like `public function getcourses($id){    //getcoursebasic
   $sql="SELECT courseId, title FROM course c
   INNER JOIN category s
   ON c.categoryId=s.categoryId
   INNER JOIN users u
   ON c.userId=u.userId
   AND c.isCompleted=2 
   AND c.isPublished=1
   WHERE u.userId != $id";
   $query=$this->db->query($sql);   
   return $query;
  }`

Comment: How do i use limt here

Comment: Try this code:  `public function getcourses($id, $limit = null){ 

//getcoursebasic 
$this->db->select('*');    
$this->db->from('course as c');
$this->db->join('category as s', 'c.categoryId = s.categoryId');
$this->db->join('users as u', 'c.userId = u.userId AND c.isCompleted=2 AND c.isPublished=1');
$this->db->where('u.userId !=', $id);
if($limit!=''){
   $this->db->limit($limit);
}
$query = $this->db->get();

return $query;
}`